# Removing link from slideshow images

Tags: views

Hello I Have Created A Slideshow Using Views  but in slideshow if anyone is clicking The link was opening node/8 I Don't Want To Show Link In When Anyone Clicks on slideshow here is my website link Windowhelpdesk.com

Comment: you can use lightbox module for slideshow,i think that is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing how your view looks like (or what slideshow module you use, if any) it is hard to give a definite answer - but check the image field in your view. If you edit the field there should be an dropdown titled 'link this image with' and right now it is probably set to 'content'. Set it to 'nothing' to remove the link.

Note: I am not sure about the exact labels as I work with a german drupal instance right now, but they should come close. The dropdown is right above the Design Settings fieldset.

Comment: I am using views slideshow module to make a slideshow in drupal So When Anyone Clicks On Image Opening A Image link I Want to remove that check on windowhelpdesk.com